# Anaconda: can not create a new environment

Tags: anaconda3

I am on Ubuntu, I'm intended to work on the GitHub project

https://github.com/stefanovic80/voila-gpx-viewer

and, according with the readme file

https://github.com/stefanovic80/voila-gpx-viewer/blob/master/README.md

I need to create a new environment, just by typing on the terminal

```
conda env create
```

as I successfully have done on my previous linux installation.

However, the terminal answer takes really long time, which could be reasonable as, according with the yml file

```
name: voila-gpx-viewer
channels:
- conda-forge
dependencies:
- bqplot=0.12
- ipyleaflet=0.16
- ipywidgets=7.7
- jupyterlab=3.4
- nodejs=16
- gpxpy=1.5
- python=3.10
- srtm.py=0.3
- voila=0.3
```

many packages have to be downloaded and installed. But no messages about download and/or installation processes makes me suspicious. At the end of the day I get this

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / Killed
```

which means something goes wrong. What's wrong here?